# Google Input tools doesn't work with Google Apps Script html page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-input-tools

I have an html page with text input box. It's expecting input text in Devanagari script. (Devanagari script is used for some of the Indian languages such as Hindi, Marathi.) The page is a part of Apps script project and it doesn't accept input from the Google Input tools. When I tested it outside of the Apps Script project, it works fine. I use the Google input tool extension for Chrome.

Additionally if I copied the word from somewhere and pasted it, it accepts it and works as intended. The problem is only with the Google Input Tools and that too when the page is made a part of Apps Script.

Comment: Are you saying the html dialog "doesn't accept input" in Devanagari?  Or that you can't transmit Devanagri to a server function?  I've created a simple html dialog and can input Devanagri text, transmit that text to a Google Spreadsheet and display it in a cell.  Perhaps there is something else wrong with your code.  I would suggest you include you code with the question.

Comment: @TheWizEd, Thanks for your reply and sorry for being late to respond. When the Google Input tool is activated, it's not supposed to take English letters as input but instead it's supposed to show a pop-up of 6 Marathi words to choose from, as the user starts typing into the text field. That does not happen. No pop-up and it takes English letters.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have a keyboard that can create Devanagari characters.  So no way to test from keyboard input.  I tried with `<input>` and`<datalist>` and I can copy a character and it works, but you probably already knew that.

Comment: @TheWizEd, Thanks for your reply and sorry for being late to respond. I am new to this forum and can't seem to get hang of it. Anyway, I think the issue is with sandbox mode of Apps script. I found this. - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#sandbox_mode